# Unwrap text is ignored in excel

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

I have asp.net mvc project, in which I have created excel document with model data and now trying to work with its appearance. I have the only problem - in just few cases my `xlWorkSheet.Cells[y, x].WrapText = false;` is just ignored...

My code for Project description field:

```
...//other fields
if (model.ColumnsNeeded.ProjectDescriptionBool)
   {
       xlWorkSheet.Cells[y, x].Style.WrapText = false;
       xlWorkSheet.Cells[y, x++] = projItem.ProjectDescription;
   }
...//other fields
```

and excel result i get, when click on the wrapped text field cas see that property wrap text is set on:
[image]

as well foreach line i had set :`xlWorkSheet.Cells[y, x].EntireRow.WrapText = false;`